# Get path of selected files in Windows explorer using python

Tags: python

I would like to select some files on my desktop and then using python script(that will be launched by keyboard combinatoion pressing) get path of all selected files.

I know how to trigger the script by key combination press ,but I have a problem with files path

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you please clarify how you invoke the script, what you want to do with the paths and what you've tried so far?

Comment: import pyHook
import pythoncom
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.Ascii == 25:
  content
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()

while True:
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()

Comment: @user3210523, you should edit that code into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I understand `pyHook` just reads the low level keyboard events. What you want to do is **not possible** with your approach. You need to get the Windows Explorer to actually tell you the paths you want to know, it needs to invoke the script itself. For this you need shell extension. You can use `pywin32` to create them in Python. Here's the [documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html) to get you started.